# How to access the JWT token value from a response object getting back in axios?

Tags: reactjs, spring-security, axios, jwt

I am developing  a react JS - spring boot application ,So I am using JWT + Spring Security to secure the rest endpoints .So I developed the spring boot application to return a JWT token like below in the response header.Now I need to access it using the react js .How can I achieve this?I am using axios to call end points from react.

This is a sample response which I get when I use the spring boot login end point.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your problem is how to get access to response headers using axios:

this is a sample code for that:

```
export const REST_API = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/api',
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});
```

then using your axios configured client

```
  REST_API.post(`/authenticate`, {
                  username: 'admin',
                  password: 'admin',
                })
              )
              .then((res: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
              console.log(response.headers.Authorization);
              });
```

hope this can help you

Comment: Thank you for answering ,but the I don't get a Authorization value in the response object like in the postman